# How to set php cookie counter same url?

Tags: php, cookies

```
$c = $_COOKIE["count"];
$c++;
setcookie("count", $c, time() + 86400, '/test', "localhost");
echo $_COOKIE["count"];
ob_flush();
flush(); 

?>
```

this is problem when change url 
example

```
http://www.example.com/test1 count=2
http://www.example.com/test3 count=1
http://www.example.com/test2 count=7
```

but i would like count only same url ?

Comment: remember that number of cookies is limited by 20 cookies per domain.

Comment: cookies won't work on localhost domain. make it at least localhost.loc

Comment: anyway, tha only sensible way to do it is to have just ONE cookie and count the rest on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the way you store the $_COOKIE.

```
setcookie("count", $c, time() + 86400, '/', 'yoursite.com');
```

The cookies you were storing will belong to that page only. This will make them accessible to the whole domain by defining a folder and domain.